# How to delete password form (ps i ve redefined user model, authentication)?

Tags: python, django, registration

i ve got a problem.
**First of all this is my idea:** a user registers his account using username and his face. The website takes his photo. And so ive  redefined authenctication, user model and so on.
But i CANT DELETE PASSWORD FORM!!!

let me show you my code first

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)

# Create your models here.

\#user's part
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
def create_user(self, username, \*\*extra_fields):

        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an username ')
    
        user = self.model(
            username=username,
            **extra_fields
            )
    
        user.set_unusable_password()
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    
    def create_staffuser(self, username):
        """
        Creates and saves a staff user with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            username,
    
        )
        user.staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    
    def create_superuser(self, username):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            username,
        )
        user.staff = True
        user.admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
username = models.CharField(
verbose_name='username',
max_length=255,
unique=True
)
main_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='main_imgs/%Y/%m', verbose_name='Главное фото')
checking_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='checking_photo/%Y/%m', verbose_name='Временное фото для проверки ')

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a admin user; non super-user
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a superuser
    password = None
    
    # notice the absence of a "Password field", that is built in.
    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [] # Email & Password are required by default.
    
    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.username
    
    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.username
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
    
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True
    
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True
    
    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        return self.staff
    
    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        "Is the user a admin member?"
        return self.admin
```

**forms**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm,AuthenticationForm

from account.models import User
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField

User = get_user_model()

class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
"""
The default

    """
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username']
    
    def clean_username(self):
        '''
        Verify username is available.
        '''
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        qs = User.objects.filter(username=username)
        if qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("username is taken")
        return username
    
    # def clean(self):
    #     '''
    #     Verify both passwords match.
    #     '''
    #     cleaned_data = super().clean()
    #     password = cleaned_data.get("password")
    #     password_2 = cleaned_data.get("password_2")
    #     if password is not None and password != password_2:
    #         self.add_error("password_2", "Your passwords must match")
    #     return cleaned_data

class UserAdminCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
"""
A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
fields, plus a repeated password.
"""
 password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
 password_2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username']
    
    # def clean(self):
    #     '''
    #     Verify both passwords match.
    #     '''
    
    
    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        # user.set_unusable_password()
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class UserAdminChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
"""A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
password hash display field.
"""
 password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username',  'is_active', 'admin']

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
class Meta:
model = User
fields = ('username',)

class SignInForm(AuthenticationForm,forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
model = User
fields = ('username',)
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin

from .forms import UserAdminCreationForm, UserAdminChangeForm
from django import forms
User = get_user_model()

admin.site.unregister(Group)

from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField

class UserAdminChangeForm2(forms.ModelForm):
password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField(label="Password", help_text="Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see this user's password.")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'is_active', 'admin', ]
    
    # def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    #     self.fields['password'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
    #     self.fields['password'].required = False

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
 The forms to add and change user instances
form = UserAdminChangeForm2
add_form = UserAdminCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ['username', 'admin', 'main_img', 'checking_photo']
    list_filter = ['admin']
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username',)}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('main_img', 'checking_photo')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('admin',)}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', )}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ['username']
    ordering = ['username']
    filter_horizontal = ()

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

**and the most interesting part is authentication.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

from account.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend
class UsernameAuthBackend(BaseBackend):
def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):

            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username=username)
                if not user.password:  # Check if password is empty
                    return user
    
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                user = User(username=username)
                user.staff = True
                user.set_unusable_password()
                user.is_superuser = True
                user.save()
            return user
    
    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

**settings.py**

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'account.authentication.UsernameAuthBackend'
]
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.User'
```

**how it works now:**

- django doesnt ask for a pasword during `createsuperuser`
- on login page i can enter any password i want(except NULL)
- during registation django requires passwords to match

BUT I DONT NEED PASSWORD FIELD

[on admin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g097x.jpg)

p.s sorry for my spanish:D